# can't copy a file from desktop to usr/scr directory in redhat linux installed on vmware

Tags: linux, vmware

I have Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 installed on VMware workstation. I want to copy a file from desktop to usr/scr folder. I tried it the normal way i.e. copy/paste but it doesn't paste in the destination folder. Please help.

Comment: Are you trying to copy from your regular workstation to your virtual machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is about copying a file from you host system to your virtual machine this link describes drag-n-drop, copy-paste, shared folder and mapping of a virtual disk to the host system:
https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp#com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-6F26D7EF-8D29-46E9-A48E-0BCBB138D333.html

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is not clear.

Guess your scenario:

```
---------------------------
|VM1(CentOS) | VM2(CentOS)|
---------------------------
|    VMware workstation   |
---------------------------
|       Your Computer     |
---------------------------
```

You want to Copy Desktop Data in *Your Computer, it depend on the OS:

1. If OS is `Windows` => Using [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php)

`WinSCP` is a open source tool for windows, default is based on FTP/SFTP/SSH. 
The GUI is friendly, I think I don't need to guide you this.
[image]

---

2. If OS is `Linux` => Using [scp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp)

`scp` is a build-in command in Linux, default is based on SSH.

e.g. Assume your destination VM private IP Address is `192.168.0.1`

```
1. Copy file from desktop to target machine (default port 22)   
    % scp /path/to/desktop/file user@192.168.0.1:/path/to/usr/src

2. Copy file from desktop to target machine (setting port 5566)   
    % scp -P 5566 /path/to/desktop/file user@192.168.0.1:/usr/src

3. Copy directory from desktop to target machine (default port 22)
    % scp -r /path/to/desktop/Dir/ user@192.168.0.1:/usr/src
```

---

Of course, if you want to copy data from VM1 to VM2, you still can follow above.

Answer (score 0):

This is the how you copy a file in a linux terminal:

```
cp <source> <destination>
```

Read more on this page: http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucp.htm

You can also use man to get help and read more about linux-commands:

```
man cp
```

As piojo commented below you need root access to copy a file to the /usr-folder. To get root access you need to login as root-user or perform the copy command as root. Use man to read about su and sudo.

```
man sudo
man su
```

Comment: Note that he will need root permissions to do this. So he should also look up "su" or "sudo". Or just run "sudo su" and see if it works with the distro's default configuration.